# Are rinsed out plastic milk jugs safe for storing water?

Tags: food-preservation, water

Over some time I have accumulated several plastic milk jugs and I'm considering using them to store water in case of an emergency.  I've rinsed them out and left them to dry, but should I worry about cleaning them further?  Should I use dish soap/scrub brushes?  Will the cleaned jugs be sealed tightly enough to prevent the water from becoming contaminated?

Comment: I'm not sure about this usage but even bottled water has an "expiration" date. How long are you planning to keep it?

Comment: @Catija as long as I can.  I know that water storage should be changed out every so often; I think every few months or so.

Comment: The date on bottled water is generally a "best before" rather than a "use by" date, probably in case it picks up flavour from the plastic. Home-bottled water may be a different matter.

Comment: If the water has sufficient chlorine in it, you can get away with just storing it as-is.  Ozonated water has no long-term anti-microbial properties, so you'll want to add a few drops (1 per L, so about 4 per gallon).  There's plenty of advice online from various 'prepper' sites.  (I just looked it up two days ago as I have 5gal jerry cans that I use for transporting water, and I thought I'd use them for storage 'til the next time I needed them).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cleaned jugs are, but ones that are only rinsed aren't. After the milk is gone, wash the inside of the jug with hot water and anti-bacterial soap. Rinse with super-purified or distilled water to avoid the risk of re-introducing contaminants to the inside of the jug. I store the filled bottles in my cold room for six months, then use the water and replace my stores.

Comment: What is the advantage of rinsing with purified or distilled water?

Comment: In fact you're better off rinsing thoroughly with tap water after sterilising (because of the chlorine). If your tap water isn't trustworthy then purified water might make sense.

Comment: @ChrisH if my tap water wasn't trustworthy I'd probably just buy bottled water and store that :)

Comment: @brandaemon yes, though in some countries people have access to unsafe piped water and use domestic purifiers.

Comment: @brandaemon -- Sorry about that. I wasn;t thinking. For some reason, I assumed you would be storing purified water as opposed to tap water, because I can't store my tap water. I have a surface well, so the water periodically picks up natural contaminants from leaves, other forest debris, or even airborne algae spores getting in through the venting. I rinse with purified or distilled water because if I rinsed with tap water, I could potentially just be re-introducing contaminants.

Comment: @Shalryn No worries; it makes sense with Chris H's comment about domestic purifiers.  If you like you can edit your answer to clarify the context.